# Office like QToolButton

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I currently try to make a QToolButton looks like equivalent in Office.

It should look like this:

[image]

I know I can access menu button with QToolButton::menu-button, but QToolButton::menu-button:hover is same as QToolButton:hover so I can't differ between both and I can't set a border just for QToolButton::menu-button. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create something like split button.

```
class SplitButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SplitButton(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void setMenu(QMenu* menu);

protected:
    void resizeEvent ( QResizeEvent * );
    void mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent * );
private:
    QFrame* line;
};
```

Added opportunity to insert menu by `setMenu()` method. `QFrame` is needed for separating button and popup menu.

At constructor just initialize base class:

```
#include <QFrame>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QResizeEvent>

SplitButton::SplitButton(QWidget *parent):
    QPushButton(parent)
{

}
```

Popup menu will be added like this:

```
void SplitButton::setMenu( QMenu* menu )
{
    if (menu) {
        line = new QFrame(this);
        line->setFrameShape(QFrame::VLine);
        line->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Sunken);

        QPushButton::setMenu(menu);
        connect(menu, &QMenu::triggered, [=](QAction *act) {
           setText(act->text());
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see we used [`QPushButton::setMenu()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#setMenu) method and connect menu [triggered](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#triggered) signal to slot, realized with labda, so you need [include c++11 compatibility](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_use_C%2B%2B11_in_your_Qt_Projects).

After we need to override resize, mousePress and keyPressed events. As minimal exmaple i done second ones.

```
void SplitButton::resizeEvent ( QResizeEvent * event )
{
    if (menu()) {
        int width  = event->size().width();
        int height = event->size().height();
        line->setGeometry(QRect(width - 18, 4, 3, height - 8));
    }
}
```

At resize event if menu is available we add frame by offset for pseudo-button.

```
void SplitButton::mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent * event )
{
    if (menu()) {
        if ( width()-event->x() <= 15 )
            showMenu();
        else
            setDown(true);
    } else {
        QPushButton::mousePressEvent(event);
    }
}
```

For mousePress event we just select what we want to do: show menu or push button.

Usage:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent), m_file(QString())
{
    setupUi(this);  

    SplitButton *split = new SplitButton;
    split->setText("B");
    QMenu *menu = new QMenu;
    menu->addAction("Y");
    menu->addAction("B");
    menu->addAction("U");

    split->setMenu(menu);
    split->setCheckable(true);
    Ui::MainWindow::mainToolBar->addWidget(split);
}
```

And you can set button [chechable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#checkable-prop) for Office-like effects.

It's just one of possible ways to realize this, I hope it will be helpful for you.

It look like on screen for me:
[image]

Of cource, it is not final result, you need repaint it like you want or use [styles](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html) for flat-style.

Comment: Thank you. Just had hoped there is a more easier way with stylesheets :/